# Searching for words with the same root as greedy

Tags: etymology

The word **greedy** comes from the Indo-European root *gher which meant something like **to like/want** ([source](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=greed&searchmode=none)).

This is also the root for the incredibly common German word gern and other every day German words. I really let my fantasy roam freely but I was not able to find another English word with that origin. 
I would find this quite surprising to see that a root with such a basic meaning almost entirely vanishes.
So my questions is:

Does anyone know of other words that have the same origin (no matter, if they are imports from Latin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At your [source](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=greed&searchmode=none) (etymonline for *greed*), if you enter *gher* or *gher-* or **gher-* as the search term you can find other words that stem, eventually, from Indo-European root *gher- in its sense *to like, want*, such as *[Eucharist](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Eucharist&allowed_in_frame=0)*, *[yearn](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yearn&allowed_in_frame=0)*, *[hortatory](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hortatory&allowed_in_frame=0)*, *[charisma](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=charisma&allowed_in_frame=0)*.

Note that PIE [*gher-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=gher) is shown in etymonline with several additional senses:
•  “to scrape, scratch” in the etymologies of *[gash](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gash&allowed_in_frame=0)* and *[character](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=character&allowed_in_frame=0)*
•  “to bristle”  for *[arugula](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=arugula&allowed_in_frame=0)* and *[urchin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=urchin&allowed_in_frame=0)*
•  “to grasp, enclose” for *[cohort](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cohort&allowed_in_frame=0)*, *[chorus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chorus&allowed_in_frame=0)*, *[yard](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yard&allowed_in_frame=0)*
• “to call out” for *[greet](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=greet&allowed_in_frame=0)*

Comment: Awesome!!! I didn't know about that function and it'll be incredibly helpful to me. Thanks a billion

Comment: on second thought... how trustworthy is Etymonline... is it more like Merriam Webster or more like dict.cc?

Comment: See the etymonline [PRINCIPAL SOURCES](http://www.etymonline.com/sources.php?allowed_in_frame=0) page, which lists books by Barnhart, Buck, Cassidy, ... OED2 ... Zoëga.  I've run into a small number of misspellings and mis-links (which were corrected within a couple of days after I sent a notice). I've seen relatively few errors besides those minor ones.

Answer (score 2):

There is ***yearn*** for which OED has

> **yearn** :   Old English, Northumbrian *giorna,* Mercian *geornan,* West Saxon *giernan,* corresponding to Old Saxon *girnean, gernean,* Old Norse *girna* (see **green** *v.*<sup>2</sup>), Gothic *gaírnjan,* related to Old English *georn,* Gothic *-gaírns* : see **yern** *adj.* and **yere** *v.*
>
> **yere** Middle English *ȝere,* representing an Old English **gerian* = Old Frisian *geria, ieria,* Old Saxon *gerôn* (Middle Low German *geren*), Old High German *gerôn, -ên, -ân* (Middle High German *geren, gern, be-gern,* German *begehren*) to desire, related to Old High German, Middle High German *ger,* Old Norse *gerr* greedy (compare Old High German *girî*, German *gier* desire, Old High German *girîg,* German *gierig* desirous, covetous, etc.); < Germanic *ger-,* whence also **yern** *adj.,* **yearn** *v.*<sup>1</sup>

This has a meaning related to *want* or *desire*.